# pytorch DataLoader not shuffling data or returning random data

Tags: python, pytorch, shuffle, dataloader

I am trying to run a toy example of my data. My end goal is for each batch from the dataloader to have different numbers for each sample that is output, but I am getting the same values, despite calling the random integers call, and shuffling my dataloader data
My pytorch dataset is implemented below:

```
class RandomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array1 = np.random.randint(0,100,20)
        self.array2 = np.random.randint(0,100,20)
        self.array3 = np.random.randint(0,100,20)
        self.array4 = np.random.randint(0,100,20)

    def __len__(self):
    #all arrays are same length
        return len(self.array1)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        first = self.array1[idx]
        sample1 = torch.Tensor(self.array1)
        sample2 = torch.Tensor(self.array2)
        sample3 = torch.Tensor(self.array3)
        sample4 = torch.Tensor(self.array4)
        return sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4
```

And I call the dataloader as

```
x = RandomDataset()
DL = DataLoader(x, batch_size=3, shuffle= True)
```

The values are all the same when i run

```
iterator = iter(DL)
output = next(iterator)
output
>>>[tensor([[21., 80., 46., 58.,  2., 21., 10., 44., 65., 79., 87., 10., 45.,  3.,
           0., 11., 29., 76., 55., 25.],
         [21., 80., 46., 58.,  2., 21., 10., 44., 65., 79., 87., 10., 45.,  3.,
           0., 11., 29., 76., 55., 25.],
         [21., 80., 46., 58.,  2., 21., 10., 44., 65., 79., 87., 10., 45.,  3.,
           0., 11., 29., 76., 55., 25.]]),
```

I thought each time i get a batch of data it would run my dataset and id get a new array of 20 numbers. What am i missing?

Comment: This [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-shuffles-at-every-epoch/135041) might be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You are always returning `self.array1` through `self.array4` for every instance of the dataset, what else are you expecting? Where you assuming those tensors would get resampled at every call? No, because they have been initialized in the `__init__`. Taking into account the fact you have `first = self.array1[idx]` I think you meant to index all four tensors in the `__getitem__` function.

So here is an example of what I believe to be what you were trying to do:

```
class RandomDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array1 = torch.randint(0,100,(20,))
        self.array2 = torch.randint(0,100,(20,))
        self.array3 = torch.randint(0,100,(20,))
        self.array4 = torch.randint(0,100,(20,))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.array1)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.array1[idx], self.array2[idx], self.array3[idx], self.array4[idx]
```

Since this use case is rather restricted, you can use [`TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset):

```
class RandomDataset(data.TensorDataset):
    def __init__(self):
        r = lambda : torch.randint(0,100,(20,))
        super().__init__(r(), r(), r(), r())
```